# Inserting data into database from Java GUI

Tags: java, database, swing

I'm trying to figure out a potential solution to a future problem

In my database, I have Subjects, Pupils, Subject_has_Pupils.

**Subject** 
French
English
Maths

**Pupils**
John
Mary
Peter

**Subject_has_pupils**
John - French
Mary - Maths

As I KNOW what the correct data to enter is I can run my own inserts fine. If I was to try Insert Peter & Spanish into into Subject_has_Pupils, the insert obviously wouldn't work.
 But how is the user to know what value to put in for the Subject? Is it Possible to have a JList that displays the possible options to the user, and can then be inserted into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a JComboBox to let the user pick only what you want him to pick.
The JComboBox should be filled with data you retrieve from your database.
I suggest taking a look at the following link if you have never worked with JComboBoxes before:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that is exactly what I was thinking of. That's going to be really helpful!